# Enter Advanced BIOS Settings

Tags: boot, bios, lenovo-laptop, overclocking

I have a **Lenovo Ideapad 110-15ACL 80TJ**, and I want to enter the **advanced BIOS settings** on it. I don't mean the the regular BIOS, but the settings unlocked when a certain key combination is pressed when the BIOS  is opened. I would like to know the **key combination** that enables the **advanced tab** on my specific model.

Comment: You should be able to do this within Windows 10 by using the Advanced Startup option.  Have you tried that method?  We are not exactly familiar with the mode you describe.  The closest thing I am aware that exists is "Advanced Startup".  So are you sure this "unlocked' BIOS option actually exists on your device?

Comment: Check your Lenovo documentation. That will describe it. Make sure you or someone else did not set up the master password.

Comment: @Ramhound, it shows online that most manufacturers have some sort of feature that enables the advanced options in the BIOS. I already know how to get to the BIOS, but I want to know if I would be able to get into the advanced options so I can change some more useful settings, as the settings in the BIOS are pretty much useless.

Comment: @John, There is no master password, and it says online that manufacturers typically wont list these key combinations in their manuals because it can cause severe damage to your computer if you use it improperly. It also isn't in the manual.

Comment: Try hitting **Fn+Tab** 3 times within BIOS, use advanced startup, to get there.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, on my recent Lenovo IdeaPad (08/2023), it works this way:

1. Open UEFI settings and disable "One Key Battery" in "configuration";
2. <kbd>F10</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (save and quit);
3. Shutdown the PC;
4. Press <kbd>R</kbd> *then* <kbd>N</kbd> (yes, it's weird to press two random keys while the computer is off);
5. Press <kbd>Insert</kbd> and if you see a menu, select "BIOS setup" with the arrow keys (yes, there is a key that can turn on the PC that is not the power button); Otherwise turn your computer on while smashing F2.

Comment: This methods enters the regular BIOS.